# why is my input not triggering my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made `input` buttons, and for some reason they are not triggering my functions ... can some one shine a light on this?

```
<div id="windowBar">
  <h3>If you were Chuck Norris...</h3>
  <input id="WindowClose" type="button" onclick="close();"></input>
  <input id="windowSmall" type="button" onclick="min();"></input>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
function close() {
  $("#inputWindow").hide(300);
}

function min() {
  if (minimize === false) {
    $("#inputWindow").hide();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','block');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','block');
    minimize = true;
  } else {
    $("#inputWindow").show();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','none');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','none');
    minimize = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: put them inside `document.ready`

Comment: @guradio, the functions are called using `onclick`. So, both functions and the DOM element are defined in DOM tree wen executing the code. If he puts the functions in `document.ready`, then they won't be defined in the global scope. The best practice is to define functions out of `$()` scope.

Comment: Where does `minimize` come from?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: it is declared on top of file.. here is a pen: http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/dGMrWB

Comment: @guradio And btw, declaring methods inside document ready would make it local to handler, so not available from global scope

Comment: yes, on of the 2 buttons gives me error, min function dont excist.. if i type the function in console i will run the function though

Comment: i wraped it in a document.ready now

Comment: @ShivaTraanman No, don't do that...

Comment: May i know your requirement?

Comment: oke so no document.ready :D its gone now

Comment: i dont get it... can some one please help? it still wont work..

Comment: Please change function name, because the close function may be confusing it with the window.close() and not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the close function name to something else like closeTag because it may be confusing it with the window.close() function. And after changing the function name it's working now please check -

```js
function closeTag() {
  $("#inputWindow").hide();
}

function minTag() {
  if (minimize === false) {
    $("#inputWindow").hide();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','block');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','block');
    minimize = true;
  } else {
    $("#inputWindow").show();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','none');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','none');
    minimize = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="windowBar">
  <h3>If you were Chuck Norris...</h3>
  <input id="WindowClose" type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeTag()"/>
  <input id="windowSmall" type="button" value="Min" onclick="minTag()"/>
  
  <div id="inputWindow">
  hide text on Close button click
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check my answer

Comment: @Jagadeesh in your case if I want to call any function from input then I can't because you fixed the function with ID that I think user don't want.

Comment: @ShivaTraanman adding  minimize = true; to close function will work for you

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript functions need to be defined above your HTML fragment. Like this:

```
<script>
function close() {
  $("#inputWindow").hide(300);
}

function min() {
  if (minimize === false) {
    $("#inputWindow").hide();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','block');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','block');
    minimize = true;
  } else {
    $("#inputWindow").show();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','none');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','none');
    minimize = false;
  }
}
</script>
<div id="windowBar">
  <h3>If you were Chuck Norris...</h3>
  <input id="WindowClose" type="button" onclick="close();"></input>
  <input id="windowSmall" type="button" onclick="min();"></input>
</div>
```

Or you can do it the jQuery way:

```
<script>
document.ready(function() {

    $('#WindowClose').click( function() {
      $("#inputWindow").hide(300);
    });

    $('#windowSmall').click( function() {
      if (minimize === false) {
        $("#inputWindow").hide();
        $('#windowBar2').css('display','block');
        $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','block');
        minimize = true;
      } else {
        $("#inputWindow").show();
        $('#windowBar2').css('display','none');
        $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','none');
        minimize = false;
      }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="windowBar">
  <h3>If you were Chuck Norris...</h3>
  <input id="WindowClose" type="button"></input>
  <input id="windowSmall" type="button"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: can you fork my pen, i cant seem to get this working either... http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/dGMrWB

Comment: I have given working snippet. can you check is it your requirement? if yes mark it as answer

Comment: I guess your requirement is when click on close it should hide input. and if click on open it should open the input window and again if we click on open it should hide. am i correct?

Comment: @Jagadeesh i dont get you, the requirements are right there in the code. the functions work just fine, i just dont get them to function when i press the button..

Comment: @ShivaTraanman make sure add  minimize = true; in close function

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){

  var minimize = false
  function close() {
    $("#inputWindow").hide(300);
    minimize = true
  }

function toggleInputWindow() {
  if (minimize === false) {
    $("#inputWindow").hide();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','block');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','block');
    minimize = true;
  } else {
    $("#inputWindow").show();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','none');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','none');
    minimize = false;
  }
}
  $('#WindowClose').on('click',function(){
      close();
  })
  
  $('#windowSmall').on('click',function(){
      toggleInputWindow();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="windowBar">
  <h3>If you were Chuck Norris...</h3>
  <input id="WindowClose" type="button" value="close"/>
  <input id="windowSmall" type="button" value="open"/>
</div>
<div id="inputWindow">input window</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add javascript:close() in on click instead of directly calling that function close()
use like this

onClick="javascript:close()",
onClick="javascript:min()".

Comment: are you writing javascript in same page itself or seperate if it is seperate please link that file to your code

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use **return false** or **event.preventDefault()** in your functions.

```
var minimize;
function close() {
  $("#inputWindow").hide(300);
  return false;
}

function min() {
  if (minimize === false) {
    $("#inputWindow").hide();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','block');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','block');
    minimize = true;
  } else {
    $("#inputWindow").show();
    $('#windowBar2').css('display','none');
    $('#windowBar2 h3').css('display','none');
    minimize = false;
  }
  return false;
}
```